# Copy Three Rows at a Time with VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet that I'm working with a previous user's VBA code on.  There are four rows of data per item in this spreadsheet, but I only want to copy the first three cells in column D for every item and paste them into another workbook.  It's currently set up to copy everything.

Every time it's ran, there could be more or less items, so it should only copy and paste cells if they have contents as well.

This is what the previous user had started.  It works fine except I want to skip copying that fourth cell every time.  The formulas you see are because as stated above, there could be more or less items each time it's used so we input the number of items, 4 for example, and then the macro knows which cells to copy.

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim FileToOpen As Variant

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
ChDrive "M:"
ChDir "M:\OpenELIS\Worksheets"
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose the Exported OE Worksheet File from The OpenELIS/Worksheets Folder", _
FileFilter:="Report Files *.xls (*.xls),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)

    'Now, copy results from wb1:
    wb1.Sheets(1).Range("D45", "D" & NumOfwells * 4 + 44 - 3).Copy

    'Now, paste to y worksheet:
    wb2.Sheets("Worksheet").Range("J2").PasteSpecial

    'Now, copy ct results from wb1:
    wb1.Sheets(1).Range("F45", "F" & NumOfwells * 4 + 44 - 3).Copy

    'Now, paste to y worksheet:
    wb2.Sheets("Worksheet").Range("L2").PasteSpecial

    'Close wb2:
    wb2.Close
    Set FileToOpen = Nothing
    Sheets(1).Activate

End If
```

Comment: Is `NumOfwells` a global variable?   ` & NumOfwells * 4 + 44 - 3` implies a variable number of cells.  Changing `wb1.Sheets(1).Range("D45", "D" & NumOfwells * 4 + 44 - 3).Copy` to `wb1.Sheets(1).Range("D45:D48").Copy` would only copy 3 cells from column D.

Comment: start from scratch

Comment: I think adding a screenshot of the data you are copying would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this by incorporating a loop into your code. For example:

```
Dim itemsToCopy as Integer
Dim Row_wb1 as Integer
Dim Row_wb2 as Integer
Dim incrementRow as Integer
Dim EndRow as Integer

Row_wb1 = 45
Row_wb2 = 2
EndRow = NumOfwells * 4 + 44 - 3

For i=1 to itemsToCopy
    'Now, copy results from wb1 into y worksheet:
    wb2.Sheets("Worksheet").Range("J" & Row_wb2 ) = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("D" & Row_wb1 , "D" & EndRow)

    'Now, copy ct results from wb1:
    wb2.Sheets("Worksheet").Range("L" & Row_wb2 ) = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("F" & Row_wb1 , "F" & EndRow)

'Increment
Row_wb1 = Row_wb1 + incrementRow
Row_wb2 = Row_wb2 + incrementRow
EndRow = EndRow + incrementRow

'Perform these operations all over again on the next item i
Next i
```

You should figure out what `NumOfwells * 4 + 44 - 3` is referring to first, as already mentioned, and determine how to limit it from 4 ranges down to 3.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice.  I about have this finished.  I have one last issue I can't seem to get over.  In wb1 I have data in Column F starting at F2.  What I need to do is copy this data to wb2 starting at M6.  The goofy part though, is that I need to insert 2 cells between each line.  I don't want to insert rows, only cells within in column M in wb2.